# Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServicesを使用してJSファイルを呼び出すと、Node呼び出しの取得でタイムアウトが発生

Tags: c#, node.js, asp.net

お世話になります。

タイトル通りNodeServicesを使用してJSを呼び出すと以下のエラーが発生します。

**エラー**

```
errorMessage: The Node invocation timed out after 60000ms.
You can change the timeout duration by setting the InvocationTimeoutMilliseconds property on NodeServicesOptions.
The first debugging step is to ensure that your Node.js function always invokes the supplied callback (or throws an exception synchronously), even if it encounters an error. Otherwise, the .NET code has no way to know that it is finished or has failed.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices.HostingModels.NodeInvocationException: The Node invocation timed out after 60000ms.
You can change the timeout duration by setting the InvocationTimeoutMilliseconds property on NodeServicesOptions.
The first debugging step is to ensure that your Node.js function always invokes the supplied callback (or throws an exception synchronously), even if it encounters an error. Otherwise, the .NET code has no way to know that it is finished or has failed.
```

**環境**
Windows10 Pro

PDFを出力するためにpuppeteerを利用しています。

ご教授お願いします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

puppeteerのバージョンを0.10.1に戻したら動作しました。.local-chromiumが動かないことが原因だと思います。